# Accessing Url.Action in a root controller of the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have this in my partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("GetTrainingModulePoints" , "Home") %>", function (data) {
      console.log(data.id);
   });
</script>
```

HomeController:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTrainingModulePoints()
{
  var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
  ZincService.TrainingService.GetTrainingModulePoints(currentUser.UserId);
  return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

the GetTrainingModulePoints method is in the HomeController in the root controller directory.
I get an 500 Internal Server Error, so it is not finding it. What is wrong with my Url.Action?

please help?
thanks

Comment: I think you are confusing HttpStatuscodes: 
HTTP 500 is an internal error (e.g. an unhandled exception within your code).
HTTP 404 would be "NotFound". 
Maybe you can use Firebug or a similar tool to see the Requests/responses and to get more error information (or add an Eventhandler for errors in the Globla.asax)

Comment: i am but i am none the wiser it has this error on the line stating GET GetTrainingModulePoints in fire bug

Comment: Thanks very much i found the problem, it cannot find the stored procedure with the same name :)

Comment: Usually when you click in the request with the error in Firebug, you should see the request/responses. If the error happens on your local machine, you should see inforamtion in the response.
Alternatively you can use a framework like elmah (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to log the errors. 
You also coud just add a try/catch around the code thats causing the error just for know - or add a 
`void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` method in you global.asax and adda breakpoint to get more information - see
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly using an Url helper to generate the url to the controller action. But you are confusing status code 500 with 404. Status code 500 means Internal Server error. This error could be caused for example if an exception is thrown inside your controller action.

The `ZincService.GetUserForId` and `ZincService.TrainingService.GetTrainingModulePoints` are good candidates for this exception.

If you use a javascript debugging tool in your browser (such as FireBug or Chrome developer toolbar) you can inspect the Network tab where you will see the exact request/response for the AJAX request. By looking at the response you might get more information about the reason for the error.

Comment: "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:52774/Home/GetTrainingModulePoints" is what i get in FireBug

Comment: Alright, now expand the request (using + sign next to it and look at the Response part). Or just put a breakpoint inside your controller action and run your application in Debug mode. When the controller action is hit you will be able to see the exception.

Comment: i found the problem thank you all very much! it says it cannot find the stored procedure with this name :)