# How to see what JSON returns in my view

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

Can some one help or explain to me how this works please?
i have in my view:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("GetTrainingModulePoints" , "Home") %>", function (json) {
    console.log(json);
    });
 </script>
```

GetTrainingModulePoints should return 4 rows each containing a value for interactiontype and a value for points

in the console log i just get [object object]?
how can i see what is in the variable json?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/firebug.png/

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [`Network tab in FireBug`](http://getfirebug.com/network) or similar javascript debugging tool. There you will see the AJAX request and all you have to do is expand the request and look at the response.

Here's for example how that might look like in FireBug for a sample AJAX request:

[image]

And if you click on the `JSON` tab you will see the output formatted as a JSON object where you could expand/collapse the properties.

If for some very weird reason you cannot use a javascript debugging tool in your web browser (I don't know even know how you could be developing a web application, but ...) you could use the `JSON.stringify` method that's built into modern browsers:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("GetTrainingModulePoints" , "Home") %>", function (json) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```

And if you are not using a modern browser which doesn't have the `JSON.stringify` method natively built-in you could still reference the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script to your page.

---

UPDATE:

OK, it seems that your confusion comes from the fact that you are getting `{"success":true}` whereas you were expecting to get the rows from your stored procedure. I know this because I answered your [`previous question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067206/accessing-url-action-in-a-root-controller-of-the-project).

Here's how your controller action look like:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTrainingModulePoints()
{
    var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
    ZincService.TrainingService.GetTrainingModulePoints(currentUser.UserId);
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you can see in this controller action you are always returning `success = true`. If you want to return the results from your stored procedure you could do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTrainingModulePoints()
{
    var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
    var modulePoints = ZincService.TrainingService.GetTrainingModulePoints(currentUser.UserId);
    return Json(
        new { 
            success = true, 
            modulePoints = modulePoints 
        }, 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

Here I assume that your `TrainingService.GetTrainingModulePoints` method is actually returning some object. If this is not the case you will have to explain what those methods are doing and how do you expect to get the output.

Comment: please see OP i added an image of what i have in FireBug

Comment: And what do you get in the `Net` tab when you inspect the response of the AJAX request as shown in my answer?

Comment: There you go. You've got the JSON you wanted to see. What else do you need? By the way did you try the `JSON.stringify` method as I suggested?

Comment: i thought i would get what my stored procedure returned? 4 rows of each two values one for interactiontype and one for points?

Comment: What stored procedure are you talking about? What does your controller action return. OK, I got it. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this who's not using firebug, you can do the same in chrome (ctrl + shift + i and then select the network tab) or fiddler.